# The problem with useState that the data goes to the firestore empty data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm aiming to update the data in the database but every time I send the data with useState it sends blank data.
Also, as I don't understand, when I print the firebase information to the console, it appears as +1 added. So it looks up-to-date but not in the database. What is the reason for this?

```
    export default postDetails = ({navigation, route}) => {
    
     const levelColl = firestore().collection('Level');
     const [levelData,setLevelData] = useState([]);
    
        
           function  StoreLevelData (){

    levelColl
        .doc(user)
        .get()
        .then(documentSnapshot=>{
            data=documentSnapshot.data();
            labels=data.levelList.labels;
            data1=data.levelList.data;
            console.log(data)
            let levelList1=[];
            for (let index = 0; index < labels.length; index++) {
              //console.log(labels[index],data[index])
             
              if(labels[index] == 'araba'){
                data1[index]+=0.0051
                console.log(data1[index])   
                
                
                
              }
              levelList1.push({
                  levelList:{
                  labels:[labels[index]],
                  data:[data1[index]]
                  }
                  
              })
            }
            console.log(levelList1) 
            setLevelData(levelList1)  

        })
      }

      levelColl
            .doc(user)
            .set({
levelData})

useEffect(() => {
      
     StoreLevelData();

  
 } , []);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqX5P.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the state and then immediately access the new data, because in react setState is asynchronous. In order for you to access the newly set state data, you will have to wait for the next re-render.
So in your case the best this to do is to create a new function below like

```
 const updateLevelList = (levelListData) => {
    setLevelData(levelListData) // Update the state here
    levelColl.doc(user)
             .set({
               levelListData // Use the same function arg instead of using state
              })
 }
```

And the call this function where you used to set the state, ie replace `setLevelData(levelList1)` with `updateLevelList(levelList1)`

Comment: Should I always use this method in such situations?

Comment: Yes you should, you shouldnt update the state and then use the value from the state variable immediately, you will always end up with the previous value in that case